# Unable to enable google analytics for bigquery linking in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have an android app which has firebase analytics enabled. I am able to see events in firebase console. Now I want to connect it with big query. As I am using a team account for firebase, asked admin to give me owner access in firebase and editor access in connected google analytics account. After getting both access I tried to connect big query in firebase but it was not allowing me to select Google Analytics option while creating link. When I hover over that option it is showing message as **"You need to be an Editor on the Google Analytics account linked to your project to modify BigQuery export"**. I am not sure what changes am I supposed to do to enable this and create a big query connection. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have the permissions in firebase you need to have Editor access to the Google Analytics Account as well in order to perform the connection. It is important that permission is given on the Account Level and not on the data view level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aleko. I realized that my problem wasnt really the permission, but someone connected the firebase project to a different GA project. Once I changed it, started working.